# jQuery div change

Tags: jquery, html, css

So this is is problem, I work on login animate form.

The idea is to show the form on click event, when form shows it displays login separation. Click on login button to login, click on singup button to call singup div element. By clicking on reset it calls reset div element with form. And when it is active, it shows singup div button, on login event it call login div with form.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".login-page").hide();
  $(".show").click(function(){
    $(".register").hide();
    $(".reset").hide();


    $(".login-page").fadeIn();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.singup').click(function(){
    $(".login-form").hide();
    $(".login-page").fadeIn();
    $(".register").show();
  }); 
});
```

```css
.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin:auto ;
  position: relative;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #e8191b;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;0
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.login{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4C4C4C;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 11px 0 0 0;

  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
} .singup{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4C4C4C;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 11px 0 0 0;

  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.message-beck-login{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4C4C4C;
  width: 49%;
  margin:  0 0 11px;

  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.reset-now{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4C4C4C;
  width: 100%;
  margin:10px 0 0 0;

  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="show">show</div>
  <div class="login-page"><div class="login-close">close</div>
    <div class="form">
      <form class="login-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <button class="login">login</button> <button class="singup">sing up</button>
        <p class="message">forget user/password<a href="#">Reset</a></p>
      </form>
      <form class="register">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail"/>
        <button class="singup">singup</button> <button class="message-beck-login"><a href="#"></a>login</button>
      </form>
      <form class="reset">
        <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail"/>
        <button class="reset-now">reset</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: here working, I have to change other parts index page.If there is a problem , contacting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `preventDefault()` on form button events to prevent submitting the form, i edited your code, take a look.

```
<html><head>
<style>

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin:auto ;
  position: relative;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #e8191b;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;0
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.login{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4C4C4C;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 11px 0 0 0;

  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
} .signup{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4C4C4C;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 11px 0 0 0;

  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.message-beck-login{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4C4C4C;
  width: 49%;
  margin:  0 0 11px;

  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.reset-now{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4C4C4C;
  width: 100%;
  margin:10px 0 0 0;

  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<!-- change to your jquery.js path -->
<script src=path/to/jquery.js></script>
</head><body>
 <div class="show">show</div>
  <div class="login-page"><div class="login-close">close</div>
    <div class="form">
      <form class="login-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <button class="login">login</button> <button class="signup">sign up</button>
        <p class="message">forget user/password<a href="#">Reset</a></p>
      </form>
      <form class="register">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail"/>
        <button class="signup">sign up</button> <button class="message-beck-login"><a href="#"></a>login</button>
      </form>
      <form class="reset">
        <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail"/>
        <button class="reset-now">reset</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.login-page').fadeOut(0);
  $('.login-close').click(function () {
    $('.login-page').fadeOut();
  });
  $('.show').click(function () {
    $('.register').fadeOut();
    $('.reset').fadeOut();
    $('.login-form').fadeIn();
    $('.login-page').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.message-beck-login').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.register').fadeOut();
    $('.reset').fadeOut();
    $('.login-form').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.signup').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.login-form').fadeOut();
    $('.register').fadeIn();
    $('.reset').fadeIn();
  });
});

</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: U welcome :) please select my answer as Correct, i appreciate!